# Hide scrolling content under fixed transparent header, scroll background

Tags: jquery, css, image, cross-browser, scroll

Lets say I have a background image, a fixed header image with transparent parts, a content div with a semi-transparent background and dynamic height in a traditional header/content/footer layout.

The effect I'm trying to achieve: scrolling background and content under a fixed header (with content hidden and background showing).

I've read a bunch of related topics, such as
[Hide Scrolling Content Under Transparent Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608214/hide-scrolling-content-under-transparent-header) etc. But they deal with situations where the background can be fixed too. Mine has to be scrollable.

I managed to get what I need by adding the same background image to a wrapper div of the header image div and scrolling it with jQuery `.scrollTop()` on window scroll event.

Reference: [**jsbin Example**](http://jsbin.com/uwubug) 
Reference: [**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vjpvd/)

The problem of this method is pretty bad sync (some lag, tearing) in all browsers **not** named Firefox.

**To clarify:** The height of content will be dynamic. `10000px` I just picked for the example. I expect it to reach that quite often though, sometimes more (AJAX feeds), and on some pages it can be close to `0`. That's why I'm syncing `.height()` too. Keep in mind that **footer div** at the bottom is ***under*** the **content div**.

And I think there ***has to be a better way***. Any suggestions?

Comment: see if `$('#header').animate({scrollTop: s}, 0);` is better in terms of performance in IE and other, i can't test it.

Comment: @AlexBall Thanks for the suggestion, tried it, but the result seems to be the same as with `$('#header').scrollTop(s);`.

Comment: @arttronics Sorry for not making myself clear, I briefly mentioned in my question that the height of content will be dynamic. 10000px I just picked for the example. I expect it to reach that quite often though, sometimes more (Ajax feeds), and on some pages can be close to 0. That's why I'm syncing `.height()` too, although maybe there's a better way to do it. About content reaching the bottom, not sure what you mean, but have in mind that footer has to be at the bottom too.

Comment: @BoLiao, I've added that your comment to clarify the SO Question a bit more. You can now delete that comment which is now obsolete. This comment will soon be deleted as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use a positioned [scroll pane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) or [scroll area](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll) to scroll your dynamic content, simply positioning it right under your fixed header?